# Window scroll with list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to create navigatable list at top of the page. 
So i have `<ul>` with some `<li>` inside. I don't need to show full list, couse i might have many of them. And i need to have opportunity to navigate inside this list with keyboard.
I add to li's `tabindex='0'` attribute.
The problem is, window start to scroll with list, after bottom elements is focused.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 1</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 2</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 3</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 4</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 5</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 6</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 7</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 8</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 9</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 10</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 11</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 12</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 13</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 14</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 15</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 16</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('li').on('focus', function() {
    $(this).addClass('focused');
});

$('li').on('focusout', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('focused');
});

$('li').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        $(e.target).prev().focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $(e.target).next().focus();
    }
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xne2p3mo/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put `e.preventDefault();` in the keydown callback, or also you can check, when it should prevent defaults, like scrolling window.

```
$('li').keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 38 || e.keyCode == 40) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        $(e.target).prev().focus();
    }
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        $(e.target).next().focus();
    }
});
```